# ¿Cómo guardar imagen de una url en la memoria interna del movil?

Tags: java, android

Necesito guardar una imagen que esta en mi servidor para la memoria interna del móvil.

Es decir dada una url guardar la imagen en la memoria interna del móvil.

El problema surgió debido a que ya lo tengo implementado para que las guarde en la tarjeta SD, pero cuando pruebo en un móvil sin tarjeta SD no las esta guardando.

Comment: Esto ya se pregunto, te recomiendo busques primeramente en el sitio.

Comment: Además deberias incluir codigo, por ejemplo el que implementaste para guardar en la tarjeta SD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Descargar imagenes y guardarlas en la SD, en caso que no tenga las guarda en la memoria interna del movil.

```
//OBTENER DATOS PRODUCTOS DEL WEB SITE LE PASO EL ARREGLO CON TODAS LAS URL DE LAS IMAGENES A DESCARGAR

public void obtDatos(String[] url) {
    int milisegundos = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        if (i>0)
            milisegundos = milisegundos+2000;
        final String urlString = url[i];
        final int finalI = i;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                descargarDatosApp(urlString, finalI);
            }
        }, milisegundos);

    }
}

public void descargarDatosApp(String url, final int finalI){
.....
    else if (finalI == 9) {
       Productos productos = new Productos();
       ArrayList<String> listaUrl = productos.obtDatosJSON(new String(responseBody), bd);
       if (listaUrl.size() > 0)
            descargarImagen(listaUrl);
       else
            pDialog.dismiss();
 }

 //UNA VES LA FUNCION descargarDatosApp DEVUELVE EL ARREGLO DE IMAGENES SE EJECUTA ESTE METODO 
 public void descargarImagen(ArrayList<String> listaUrl) {
    saveImagenes.setTotalUrl(listaUrl.size());
    this.listaUrl_ = listaUrl;
    //for (int i = 0; i < listaUrl.size(); i++) {
    if (listaUrl.size() > 0)
        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(listaUrl.get(saveImagenes.getPosicion()-1));
    //}
}

public  void metodoRecursivo(){
    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(this.listaUrl_.get(saveImagenes.getPosicion()-1));
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Starting download");
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... listaUrl) {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File root = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/appLuisgonzalez");
            if (!root.exists())
                root.mkdir();
            String url_aux = listaUrl[0];
            URL url = new URL(url_aux);

            String[] urlLista = url_aux.split("/");
            String nombre = "";
            nombre = urlLista[urlLista.length - 3];
            nombre +="_"+urlLista[urlLista.length - 2];
            nombre +="_"+urlLista[urlLista.length - 1];
            nombre = nombre.replaceAll("-", "_");
            nombre = nombre.toLowerCase();

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            //int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream(), 8192);
            //SI CREO EL DIRECTORIO ES QUE EXISTE SD, EN CASO QUE NO LO GUARDAMOS EN LA MEMORIA INTERNA
            if (root.exists()) {
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root.toString() + "/" + nombre);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } else {
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                InputStream inputStream = conection.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                FileOutputStream outputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(nombre + ".JPEG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(byteArray);
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error 1:", " Contacte al administrador");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println("Downloaded");
        saveImagenes.setPosicion(saveImagenes.getPosicion() + 1);
        if (saveImagenes.getPosicion() == saveImagenes.getTotalUrl())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        else{
            metodoRecursivo();
        }

    }

}
```

CLASE PRODUCTOS

```
public class Productos {
private long id;
private String id_producto;
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private String decripcion_corta;
private String nombre_img;

public Productos() {}

public Productos(String id_producto, String nombre, String descripcion, String decripcion_corta, String nombre_img) {
    this.id_producto = id_producto;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.decripcion_corta = decripcion_corta;
    this.nombre_img = nombre_img;
}

public String getId_producto() {
    return id_producto;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public String getDecripcion_corta() {
    return decripcion_corta;
}

public String getNombre_img() {
    return nombre_img;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setId_producto(String id_producto) {
    this.id_producto = id_producto;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public void setDecripcion_corta(String decripcion_corta) {
    this.decripcion_corta = decripcion_corta;
}

public void setNombre_img(String nombre_img) {
    this.nombre_img = nombre_img;
}

//INSERTAR DATOS EN LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
public boolean insertarProductos(BD bd){
    boolean insertado = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();
    if(bd != null){
        ContentValues nuevoProducto = new ContentValues();
        nuevoProducto.put("id_producto", getId_producto());
        nuevoProducto.put("nombre_producto",getNombre());
        nuevoProducto.put("descripcion_producto",getDescripcion());
        nuevoProducto.put("descrip_corta_producto",getDecripcion_corta());
        nuevoProducto.put("nombre_img",getNombre_img());
        db.insert("productos", null, nuevoProducto);
        insertado = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return  insertado;
}
//COMPROBAR SI EXISTE EL PRODUCTO
public boolean comprobarExistente(BD bd){
    boolean insertar = true;
    if (bd != null){
        final SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor productos = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto="+getId_producto(), null);
        if (productos.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                insertar = false;
            } while(productos.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    }
    return insertar;
}

//OBTENER ARREGLO DEL JSON
public ArrayList<String>  obtDatosJSON(String response, BD db){
    ArrayList<String> listaUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            setId_producto(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
            setNombre(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_title"));
            setDescripcion(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            setDecripcion_corta(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("excerpt"));
            String urlImg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("guid");
            if (comprobarExistente(db)){
                listaUrl.add(urlImg);
                String[] urlLista = urlImg.split("/");
                nombre = urlLista[urlLista.length - 3];
                nombre +="_"+urlLista[urlLista.length - 2];
                nombre +="_"+urlLista[urlLista.length - 1];
                nombre = nombre.replaceAll("-","_");
                nombre = nombre.toLowerCase();
                setNombre_img(nombre);
                Log.e("Nombre imagen:", getNombre_img());
                insertarProductos(db);
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: esto no es una respuesta, edita tu pregunta y añade el código allí para facilitar la comprensión del problema y que le resulte más fácil a la gente responder. Gracias

Comment: Acabo de encontrar el problema y es el php, que no esta devolviendo bien las url de las imágenes, así que el código anterior esta perfecto, lo dejo como respuesta a mi pregunta, Muchas Gracias

Comment: "ESTO FUNCIONA A LA PERFECCIÓN EL PROBLEMA ESTA EN QUE". No entiendo si realmente es una solución o una edición a tu pregunta. Favor de clarificar en la publicación.

Comment: Ya la edite, es la respuesta a mi primera pregunta.